# How can I create a Windows error message with a custom icon?

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I want to make a program that allows me to open windows popups with custom error icons, but I can't figure it out.

I asked chatgpt, and it gave me this:

```py
import ctypes
import urllib.request

# Set up the parameters for the error message
title = "[CUSTOM ERROR TITLE]"
message = "[CUSTOM ERROR MESSAGE]"
style = 0x10 | 0x0
icon_url = "[IMGUR LINK]"

# Download the icon and save it locally
urllib.request.urlretrieve(icon_url, "icon.png")

# Display the error message with the custom image
ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(None, message, title, style, 0, "icon.png")
```

Running this code works, but only has the normal critical error icon. Do I have to manually make a custom Tk window to do this, or is there another way?

Comment: I thought it was only banned to answer questions, I was just putting the current code that I have...

Comment: The reason ChatGPT is banned is because it spits out plausible looking but completely wrong answers, and it's too much work to go around cleaning up after it.  Congratulations on learning that the hard way.

Comment: I once had the task of displaying a message box with custom colors.  The only way I could do it was to re-implement the whole message box from scratch.  I was proud of the result, but it definitely wasn't worth the effort it took.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yeah, I guess I'll have to do that. If I do end up doing that, I'll make a library out of it so other people don't have to.